# If I breed a male Pokemon with a Ditto is the gender going to be male or will the gender be random?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've got a male [Eevee](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/133.shtml), and a [Ditto](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/132.shtml). I'd like to have a female Eevee so I can have a female [Sylveon](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/700.shtml). So if I breed a male with a Ditto will it always come back as a male, or will the gender be random?

Update (10/20): Well finally after breeding my Eevee with a Ditto I finally managed to get one.
[image: Originally posted on Kalos]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The gender will be of normal Eevee distribution, which is to say 87.5% male, 12.5% female.

Comment: Well I'm really trying for a female one. Would it be easier for me to keep breeding until I eventually get a female one, or would I be better off looking on Route 10 (where they're found in the wild)? I'm guessing that breeding is the best option.

Comment: If you just want a female Eevee you are better off in the wild (from my personal experience). But if you want an eevee to evolve you are probably better off just breeding to have low level ones and hoping another female comes up in the process anyway.

Comment: @Reafexus - The other option of course is to trade for one on GTS, if you're having no luck breeding/catching one

Comment: @user56652 Another option for getting a female Eevee putting a male Pokemon with Cute Charm (like a male Sylveon) at the head of your party. Cute Charm increases the chances of encountering an opposite-gendered wild Pokemon to 66.7%, regardless of gender distributions.